# Plotting $z=x^y$ using Matlab

Tags: graphing-functions, matlab

I know that $0^0$ is not generally defined to be any value since one of the reasons is that $z=x^y$ is discontinuous at $(x,y)=(0,0)$.

So I wanted to plot the graph of $z=x^y$ by myself using Matlab and I wrote the following Matlab code.

```
%% Create mesh grid
eps = 0.1; resolution = 100;
u = linspace(eps,2.0,resolution);
v = linspace(-2.0,2.0,resolution);
[x,y] = meshgrid(u,v);

%% Define z=x^y
z = x.^y;
mesh(x,y,z); xlabel('x'); ylabel('y'); zlabel('z');
```

So the result is
[my $z=x^y$ plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfcmq.png)

But it doesn't make any sense since the shown graph does not reveal any discontinuity at $(x,y)=(0,0)$.

Of course I made a regularization because of singularity at the origin. But Wolfram alpha web service shows different result. Below is the result.

[Wolfram alpha result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iB0BU.png)

Comment: Have you tried decreasing your `eps`? I guess you are not close enough to the discontinuity

Comment: Also I think that you should rotate the graph as you should expect a spike at $(x,y)=(2,2)$.

Comment: Agree with reducing eps.  Also you should zlim the plot if you want to compare:  zlim([0 4])

Comment: I decreased eps to 0.001 and it seems hopeless to see a correct result.